# How to transform a list of lists into a single list in prolog

Tags: prolog

I am wondering how to transform a list that looks like this: `[[a,b,c], [[b,c],[a,c],[a,b]]` ,which indicates the vertices adjacent to every vertex in the first sub list, to a list that looks like this: `[*adj*(a,[b,c]), *adj*(b,[a,c]), *adj*(c,[a,b])]`

I am wondering if using maplist would help in this situation or if there is a list operation I can use to get the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that this works:

```
map([X,Y],L) :- map(X,Y,L).

map([],[],[]).
map([H1|T1],[H2|T2],[adj(H1,H2)|T3]) :- map(T1,T2,T3).

?- map([[a,b,c], [[b,c],[a,c],[a,b]]],X).
```

That gives:

```
X = [foo(a, [b, c]), foo(b, [a, c]), foo(c, [a, b])].
```

Comment: Thank you! I was also wondering if there is a way to store the list map gives you and use it inside another predicate in prolog?

Answer (score 1):

Rolling your own isn't that difficult. Something like this:

```
transform( [Xs,Ys] , Zs ) :- transform( Xs, Ys , Zs ) .

transform( []     , []     , []            ) .
transform( [X|Xs] , [Y|Ys] , [adj(X,Y)|Zs] ) :- transform(Xs,Ys,Zs) .
```

**Note:** the above code makes the assumption that both the first element in the source list, the list of vertices, and the second element, the list of adjacencies for each vertice, are of equal lengths. If that's not the case, it will behave badly.

When run:

```
?- transform(
  [
    [a,b,c],
    [ [b,c], [a,c], [a,b] ]
  ] ,
  Zs
) .
```

Yields the desired:

```
Zs = [
       adj( a, [b,c] ) ,
       adj( b, [a,c] ) ,
       adj( c, [a,b] )
     ]
```

https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/usILmota.pl